# Парсинг одинаковых тэгов BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, парсер, beautiful-soup

Есть страница HTML вот такой структуры.

```
<div class="col-md-12">
        <p class="appeal-element-bottom"><span> Опубликовано: </span> 01.01.0001</p>
        <p class="appeal-element-bottom"><span> Автор: </span> Иванов Иван Иванович</p> 
        <p class="appeal-element-bottom"><span> Регион: </span> Саратовская область</p>
    </div>
```

Делаю парсинг, но из за одинаковых тегов всегда извлекается только первый результат. Как получить остальные?

```
soup=bs4.BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
    divs = soup.find('div', class_='appeals-list-container')
    appeals = soup.find_all('div', class_='appeal-element')
    for appael in appeals:
        try:
            appeal_date = appael.find('p', class_='appeal-element-bottom').text.strip().replace('Опубликовано: ', '')
        except:
            appeal_date=''
        try:
            region = appael.find('p', class_='appeal-element-bottom').text.strip()
        except:
            region=''
```

appeal-element это родительский тэг который я не указал в данном примере.

Comment: Не совсем понятно, что Вы хотите распарсить. Если вам нужно распарсить все div с классом `appeals-list-container` , то нужно указать один общий родительский элемент. Затем `divs = soup.find_all('div', class_='appeals-list-container')` . И потом в цикле парсить каждый.

Comment: В данном конкретном случае я хочу получить регион. Но когда я делаю   region = appael.find('p', class_='appeal-element-bottom').text.strip()
У меня в переменную записывается дата, а не регион.

Comment: Для получения данных `Региона` можете попробовать использовать `appael.find_all('p', class_='appeal-element-bottom')[2]` - то есть получать список значений всех тегов, но выбирать один конкретный.

Comment: Также можете сделать поиск по тексту. https://stackoverflow.com/a/31959218/10898133

Comment: Первый вариант сработал. Спасибо!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Для получения данных региона используйте

```
appael.find_all('p', class_='appeal-element-bottom')[2]
```

то есть получаете список значений всех тегов `p` с классом `appeal-element-bottom` внутри `appeal` и выбираете один конкретный элемент (для этого указывается индекс элемента списка - это *порядковый номер тега - 1*; в данном случае - 2).

Также можете попробовать воспользоваться [поиском по тексту](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31959218/10898133).